# Why is bash behaving differently when it takes argument in braces?

Tags: bash, function, dollar-sign, braces

Input: `range 6`

```
function range {
        echo {0..$1}
        echo {0..6}
        if [[ $1 =~ 6 ]]
        then
          echo "Equal"
        fi
}
```

Output:

```
{0..6}

0 1 2 3 4 5 6
```

Why is the output different whereas `$1` and 6 is equal?

Answer (score 0):

The curly-braces get expanded before $-variables are expanded, and the curly-brace range syntax simply doesn't recognize anything other than a pair of numbers with dots in between.